# Shortcut to cleanup folder by name in mac

Tags: macos, mac, automator, osx-mountain-lion

Is there any shortcut to clean up folder icons in mac? or any automator task ?

[image]

**Update - Got the answer**

Apple has a shortcut for this. Finder > Clean Up By - name [cmd+opt+1]

[image]

Comment: I believe this was asked on ask different: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52535/clean-up-file-names-using-automator

Comment: Its not the way I want. I just need to rearrange and align folders properly to grid.

Comment: You should add an answer to your question, then you can get up votes on that too!

Answer (score 1):

Open automator and select the following items.  You can create your own automator script this way.

[image]

Comment: I tried this but I need more generic type workflow. In this I have to specify the folder, otherwise it won't work. My idea is to assign a keyboard shortcut & use it to arrange icons [files/folder] from any finder window.

Comment: You mean specifying the Desktop folder won't work?

Comment: Or just create one for each folder and give it an easy to remember name, then just use spotlight.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut to cleanup folder by name on OSX

There's already a default shortcut for this, ⌥⌘1 (<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>).

Comment: You are repeating the Update of OP